# Excel Pie Chart with categories and pulled slices

Tags: excel, pie-chart

Is there a way to make a pie chart like this in Excel? All I can find are ways to pull individual slices, but not keep them together with other slices in the same category. I need to keep them together, but pulled out as a group.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently a way to do this in Excel.

What you would have to do is make multiple pie charts.  Each pie chart would have a different category visible (i.e. change the fill and outline of each of the other slices to "No fill" so only the category you want to see shows). Then you would have to overlay the charts to get the desired effect (Make sure the background of the charts on top has "No fill", so you can see the charts below).